# Why http client responds to a [FIN, ACK] with a [ACK], (without responding a [FIN, ACK])?

Tags: apache, http, tcp, httpconnection

Server sends a [FIN, ACK] after the connection timeout, sometimes client responds with a [FIN, ACK] and collection get closed properly. But sometimes client responds with a [ACK] and try to send data to the server.

Can someone please explain why sometime the client responds [ACK]?